# Why are there no Empathen

Tags: etymology, history

There are *Psychopathen*, *Soziopathen*, *Homöopathen*,...

But why are there no *Empathen*? Why are they called *Empathiker*?
duden.de, for example, has an entry for [*Empathiker*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Empathiker), but not for *Empath*.

And what are people called who are *apathisch*?

Comment: **"Why?"** is not a very useful question when you are talking about languages. There is rarely a logical reason why a language develops as it does

Comment: @PiedPiper I think this is rather about whether there's a rule that says whether *-path* or *-pathiker* is to be uesd.

Comment: *Apathiker* ...

Comment: Wer behauptet, dass "Empath" nicht benutzt wird?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Betazoids in german Star Trek where called Empathen ^^

Comment: @CarstenS   Vielleicht spricht man von Soziopathen und Psychopathen häufiger als von Empathen, weil erstere häufiger vorkommen?

Comment: @mtwde, exactly my first thought.

Comment: @CarstenS Ich habe mal ergänzt, dass zumindest der Duden keinen Empathen, sondern nur Empathiker kennt

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass in den Honor-Harrington-Büchern (deutsche Übersetzung) die Baumkatzen als Empathen (möglicherweise mit dem Präfix Tele-) bezeichnet werden.

Comment: Anzahl der Verwendung von "Empathiker", die ich je gehört habe: 0. Von "Empathen": diverse, meist in Science Fiction.

Comment: [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=untertitel;q=empath) liefert auch nur Treffer bei Video-Untertiteln.

Comment: @PiedPiper: Wenn man nicht davon ausgeht, dass sich Sprache aus unergründlichen Zufällen entwickelt, dann liegt jedem Phänomen eine Ursache zu Grunde. Ob Du oder ein anderer sie kennt ist eine andere Frage, aber die Frage nach dem Wieso zum Tabu zu erklären ist für eine Gruppe, die sich ausdrücklich mit Sprache beschäftigt, m.E. verfehlt.

Comment: @userunknown Ich wollte solche Fragen keineswegs zum Tabu erklären, sondern, nur meine Meinung äussern, dass sie nicht sehr sinnvoll sind. Da der geballte Sachverstand in diesem Forum noch keine befriedigende Antwort geliefert hat, ist es durchaus denkbar, dass es in diesem Fall um Zufall handelt

Answer (score 3):

Wörter wie *Psychopath* und *Soziopath* sind junge Kunstwörter. Der dem Griechischen entlehnte Wortbestandteil *-path* bezeichnet hier eine Person, die unter einer Krankheit leidet.

Das Wort *Empathie* hat eine kuriose Geschichte: Es ist die deutsche Entsprechung des Englischen *empathy*, das von Edward Titchener als Übersetzung des deutschen Begriffs *Einfühlung* eingeführt wurde. ([Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/empathy/#HisInt))

Da griechisch *em-patheia* schlicht *Mit-Gefühl* entspricht, ergibt eine Reanalyse zu *Em-path* mit *-path* in der Bedeutung "Person, die unter einer Krankheit leidet" keinen Sinn. (Das ist allerdings kein absolutes Hindernis, wie die in der Science Fiction wohl beliebte Verwendung des Begriffs *Empath* zeigt.)

Formale Parallelen zu *Empathie* – *Empathiker* finden sich bei *Chemie* – *Chemiker*, *Empirie* – *Empiriker*, *Theorie* – *Theoretiker*.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a source, but as far as I know it depends on the syllables of the word:
One syllable before the '*path*' leads to -*pathiker*, more syllables lead to -*path*.

Answer (score 0):

Empathie is the skill, Empathiker are thus craftsmen in the trade of Empathik, with suffixes according to the rules of greek-rooted words: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_griechischer_Suffixe

Alternatively it could have been Empathist, Or Empathistiker, i i am reading that table right.